# jquery dynamically add to accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Using the [example from jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#fillspace), I tried dynamically adding a section to the accordion (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910645/add-items-to-a-jquery-accordion-with-jquery)), but I can't get the accordion to resize properly. The new section overflows the accordion container, and when it's clicked, it gets squished into the container, hiding the section contents. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZU4S7/).

**How can I add a section and get the accordion to resize?**

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        fillSpace: true
    });

    // I want to dynamically add sections to the accordion,
    // but it doesn't resize properly...
    $("#accordion")
                .append('<h3><a href="#">New Section</a></h3><div><p>hello world</p></div>')
                .accordion("destroy")
                .accordion({ fillSpace:true })
                .accordion("resize")
        ;

    $("#accordionResizer").resizable({
        minHeight: 140,
        resize: function() {
            $("#accordion").accordion("resize");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the height attribute on the accordionResizer (`height:220px`), everything works as it should. It looks like the height you've picked is too low for the contents - hence the overflow.

If you need something other than the default height to fit the contents, try dynamically assigning the height of the accordionResizer each time you add a new section.

something like...

```
var height = $("#accordion h3").size() * $("#accordion h3:first").height() + 50;
      // add 50px to     allow room for the section contents.
$("#accordionResizer").height(height);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI Accordion takes the element size from when it's called. You'd have to call some kind of refresh method on it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue and answer are fine (as you can still destroy and recreate the accordion), but are dated now with the introduction of jQuery 1.10.0 adding a new [refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-refresh) method which handles the resizing fine.  Given the new version of jQuery, I would now write the code as follows:

```
$(function() {
    // Add the following parameters otherwise the last entry
    // added to the accordion will be active after the refresh.
    //
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true, // Let's you squash all of the headings
        active: false // Defaults to having all of the headings squashed
    });

    // Now you can dynamically add to the accordion and refresh it.
    //
    $("#accordion")
            .append('<h3><a href="#">New Section</a></h3><div><p>hello world</p></div>')
            .accordion("refresh"); // A graceful recreation of the accordion.
});
```