# jQuery event delegation and the Rails asset pipeline

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui, asset-pipeline

I'm using jQuery UI within my Rails 3.1 application. It's a basic CRUD application, structured with a couple of 'main' controllers that handle the overall application structure - landing pages and workflow, and then other controllers which handle the model interactions (via ajax requests).

A lot of my application uses inline editing for forms and such, and I'm got a lot of partials like the following:

**_action_list.html.erb**

```
<script>
    $("#action-new").button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-plus"
        }
    });

    $(".buttonset").buttonset();

    $("#actions").accordion();  
</script>


<div id="actions" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <% @segment.action_items.each do |action_item| %>
            <%= render action_item %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div id="new-action">
</div>

<br />
<%= link_to "New Action",
 new_report_segment_action_item_path(@segment.report, @segment),
 {:id => "action-new", :method => :get, :remote => true} %>
```

which is rendered through **action_list.js.erb**:

```
$("#actions").html("<%= escape_javascript(render "action_list") %>")
```

Everything works as it should the first time the page loads, however after going through the edit process (render edit form -> save -> rerender action_list) some jQuery elements (the accordion in this case) don't render as they should i.e without the jQuery styling applied. I'm aware that this is probably due to the element needing to be re-bound using event delegation - broadly detailed [here](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2010/03/4/event-delegation-with-jquery) & [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_get_and_use_the_server_response_from_an_AJAX_request.3F).

So, I want to extract the inline JS into the asset pipeline files, and then implement event delegation so rebinding elements happens in the background - I want to keep all JS out of my views. How would I accomplish this 'the Rails way' without resorting to writing all of my ajax functionality in jQuery?

Comment: you should have a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910645/add-items-to-a-jquery-accordion-with-jquery

Comment: ...and there: http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs

Comment: They don't really cover the question at all. The problem isn't accordion specific, and I shouldn't need a plugin to accomplish straight forward functionality. I've already overcome both of these problems using the core .delegate() methods. The question centres around implementing this using the Rails UJS asset pipeline..

Comment: sorry, went over my head. I don't know then.