# ASP.NET UpdatePanel's and JQuery UI Accordian's

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery, updatepanel

I am having an issue. I have this code:

```
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Categories</h3>
        <div style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;"><p><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddCategory" CssClass="button" Text="Add New Category" OnClientClick="OpenAddNewCategoryDialog(); return false;" /></p>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnlUpdateCategories">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblCategories"></asp:Table>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        <h3>Access Levels</h3>
        <div>
            <p>This is section 2 content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My table that is in the ContentTemplate is being dynamically created. Everything is working fine except one annoying problem. When there is a row added to the table after my updatepanel updates, the jquery ui accordion gains a scrollbar. If I hit F5 to refresh the page, the scrollbar is not there and the accordion grows with the content, as expected.

It seems like whenever there is an ajax call and the updatepanel updates, is when the scrollbar appears instead of expanding the height of the accordion. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910645/add-items-to-a-jquery-accordion-with-jquery  After your ajax returns, destroy and recreate the accordion.

Comment: @pkExec - Same result. Although it does seem like if I destroy it, that would fix it. But no luck with that suggestion

Comment: Can u add screen shot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

after async post back event it call your javascript function so you can call accordion function and it update html. try it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('.test').accordion();
    }); 



var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        // call your accordion javascript function here for i.e. $('.test').accordion();
    }
</script>
```